# Cron Jobs - connect using SOAP

Tags: php, soap, cron

I have a Cron job that works perfectly in command line (`Terminal Mac`) but when run as a Cron job it fails at loading a soap request.

```
Code..
    $soapul= "https://connect.codelocks.com/Controllers/Device/NetCode.asmx?wsdl";
    $oSoapClientZ = new SoapClient($soapul);
....
```

Is this wrong to load a soap request in like this as a Cron job?

Comment: First Step : Make sure that your cron is getting executed.

Comment: Can you show us the log file of the executed cronjob?